# ¿Como colocar los datos de un for en un text Area?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, textarea

Tengo una consulta respecto a mi código,quiero colocar los datos generados de un array que esta dentro de un for que se muestren dentro de un área de texto pero únicamente se muestra el ultimo elemento, como puedo solucionar esto?
Gracias.
Aqui dejo como lo estaba realizando:

```
 String op,op1;
    double pro,pro1;
    int i;
    op =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de simbolos:");
    pro=Double.parseDouble(op); 
    double Elementos[] = new double [50]; 
      for(  i = 0; i < pro; i ++ ){
           op1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Ingrese la probabilidad del dato Nro "+ ( i+1 ) );
                    pro1 = Double.parseDouble( op1 );
                    Elementos[ i ] = pro1;
                     
    }
        for (int x = 0; x < Elementos.length; x++) {
    for ( i = 0; i < Elementos.length-x-1; i++) {
        if(Elementos[i] < Elementos[i+1]){
            double tmp = Elementos[i+1];
            Elementos[i+1] = Elementos[i];
            Elementos[i] = tmp;
             
        }  
    }
}
for(i=0;i<pro;i++){
    System.out.println(Elementos[i]);
    txtbinario.setText("S"+(i+1)+" = "+Elementos[i]+"\n");
}

}
```

Comment: Necesitas contacter tu informacion y has uso de salto de lineas para que la informacion no quede pegada, si necesitas concatenar mucha informacion usa la clase StringBuilder en lugar del String.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar contenido al texto actual agregando al texto actual existente. Incluí una linea previo al `for` para limpiar el area. Si deseas no perder los datos actuales, esa linea no seria necesaria.

```
txtbinario.setText(""); //limpiar txtbinario
for(i=0;i<pro;i++){
   System.out.println(Elementos[i]);
   txtbinario.setText(txtbinario.getText()+"S"+(i+1)+" = "+Elementos[i]+"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

una opcion no es muy fina pero te puede ayudar si quieres mostrar todo lo como en una cadena, seria lo siguiente en el ultimo for:

```
String texto="";
    int cont=0;         
    for(i=0;i<pro;i++){
        
        cont++;
        System.out.println(Elementos[i]);
        texto=texto+" "+Elementos[i];
        
    }
    txtbinario.setText("S"+cont+" = "+texto+"\n");
```

Ahora si quieres el promedio podria ser lo siguiente:

```
        int prom=0;
        int cont=0;         
        for(i=0;i<pro;i++){
            
            cont++;
            System.out.println(Elementos[i]);
            prom=prom+(int)Elementos[i];
            
        }
        prom=prom/cont;
        txtbinario.setText("S"+cont+" = "+prom+"\n");
```

o sumar bueno alli vas modificando, espero que te ilumine el camino. Saludos